# reCAPTCHA from Google

Tags: php, forms, authentication, recaptcha

I'm a new with php and I tried to use captcha for a login form and I can't make it work, if I put the password and username correctly it logs in without need of captcha and that way it is useless to use captcha.

recaptchalib.php is this one: https://github.com/google/ReCAPTCHA/blob/master/php/recaptchalib.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!empty($_SESSION['login_user']))
{
header('Location: home.php');
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Account Generator</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.shake.js"></script>
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#login').click(function()
            {
            var username=$("#username").val();
            var password=$("#password").val();
            var dataString = 'username='+username+'&password='+password;
            if($.trim(username).length>0 && $.trim(password).length>0)
            {


            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajaxLogin.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function(){ $("#login").val('Connecting...');},
            success: function(data){
            if(data)
            {
            $("body").load("home.php").hide().fadeIn(1500).delay(6000);
            }
            else
            {
             $("#login").val('Login')
             $("#error").html("<span style='color:#cc0000'>Error:</span> Invalid username and password. ");
            }
            }
            });

            }
            return false;
            });


            });
        </script><script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
</head>

<body><?php

require_once "recaptchalib.php";

?>
<div id="main">

<div id="box"><?php
      if ($response != null && $response->success) {
        echo "Hi " . $_POST["name"] . " (" . $_POST["email"] . "), thanks for submitting the form!";
      } else {
    ?>
<form action="" method="post">
<label>Username</label> 
<input type="text" name="username" class="input" autocomplete="off" id="username"/>
<label>Password </label>
<input type="password" name="password" class="input" autocomplete="off" id="password"/><br/>

<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Le06gETAAAAAL8Mg-K21nbLCKaeoCLrY82IQ-CS"></div>

<input type="submit" class="button button-primary" value="Log In" id="login"/> 
<span class='msg'></span> 
<div id="error">

</div>  

</div>
</form><?php } ?>   
</div>

</div>

<?php 
      foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        echo '<p><strong>' . $key.':</strong> '.$value.'</p>';
      }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have an [example](https://github.com/google/ReCAPTCHA/blob/master/php/example-captcha.php) on the repository. Plus, I guess this is not `ajaxLogin.php` ?

Comment: I'm confused - why do you want reCaptcha on a **log-in** form? If a user has the correct username/password credentials isn't that enough? One would usually use reCaptcha on a registration form to prevent bots signing up in the first place.

Comment: I want to use it to prevent bruteforcing